# controlling fast swipe in the pdf

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, pdf

I am working on pdf reader app.i am using gestures for rendering next page from the current page,for this i am using swipe.
1.My work is working well.
2. For each time i am calling drawLayer using setNeedsDisplay.
3.My app is working fine if the swipe is slow means while page rendering is in process if i swipe then it is getting crashing.

can any one help me to solve this issue with some library files.
Thank you all,

Comment: Cant help you if you dont give more information. Also if your app is crashing, its probably NOT working well.

Comment: problem occurs only when before completing rendering of one page if we again  swipes.which information can i provide,do you need drawLayer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [problem when swipe using very fast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848414/problem-when-swipe-using-very-fast)

Comment: this is the answer for the above question   [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(loadPagesAccordingToCurrentOrientation) object:nil];
[self performSelector:@selector(loadPagesAccordingToCurrentOrientation) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the answer for the above question [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(loadPagesAccordingToCurrentOrientation) object:nil]; [self performSelector:@selector(loadPagesAccordingToCurrentOrientation) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];