# problem when swipe using very fast

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am developing an pdf reader in which i have to load each page of the pdf book on finger swipe. For each swipe i am incrementing one page it is working fine if i am swiping slowly.where it is not at all working if the swipe is so fast it gets crashed.

hi folks i resolved the above issue with the NSobject class reference   it has only two lines..

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(loadPagesAccordingToCurrentOrientation) object:nil];
[self performSelector:@selector(loadPagesAccordingToCurrentOrientation) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
```

Comment: Your code formatting is broken. Would you mind taking the time to fix it?

Comment: in case you don't know how to [format lines as code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) on SO (it looks like in the past, others did it for you), you do so by indenting the lines four spaces. The "{}" button in the editor toolbar does this for you. Edit your question and try it out. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting.

Comment: ... Also, stop posting the same question more than once. Read the SO FAQs for more on how SO is structured, and how you should use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some of the code is used for my problem

[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(loadPagesAccordingToCurrentOrientation) object:nil];

[self performSelector:@selector(loadPagesAccordingToCurrentOrientation) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];

Answer (score 1):

I cant be sure but It feels like you are not accounting for the use case where one page may not have finished rendering while another comes into the pipe.

The line in

`loadSinglePageWithWidth:(float)width andHeight:(float)height`

`myPageRef = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(...`

feels especially unstable even if wrapped in the @synchronised pragma.

I think you need to account for that situation and cancel any existing renderings/animations before allowing the next one to begin.

SO isnt a debugger.